# fitness function in PHP

Tags: java, php, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I looked a whole day after an example to implement the 'fitness function' in a Genetic algorithm. (I implemented already a 'begin population', 'mutation' and permutation). The following step is the 'fitness function'. Does anyone have an example of calculating the 'fitness' in PHP? Java or C# is OK as well.

Comment: Where is the following function?

Comment: I assume "fitness" is a fixed term in the context of genetic programming?

Comment: Yes: you can find a definition on wikipedia: thanks for your reply! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_function

Comment: Fitness depends on what you have and you're trying to do. For example, if you're looking at a car, the fitness could be different depending on whether you want to have a high top speed, get a lot of MPGs, not die in a crash....

Comment: OK @DHall, I try to implement the assignment problem (assign a student to an internship). But now, 'Joe Phillips' has helped me well on my way. Thanks for your reply anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fitness function will simply rank one member of your population. The item with the highest fitness function "wins" and then has intercourse with a new member of the population in the next round.

It is up to you how to define the fitness of a member. It is up to this function to determine what will win in Brains vs. Brawn, so to speak.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thanks for your helpfull reply!

Answer (score 1):

Create a java, C or C# software wich implement your personal fitness function. Later, you can use the `exec()` function to execute the software and collect the output. For example:

```
<?php
    $output = array();
    exec("/path/to/fitness_function_executable", $output);
    print_r($output);
?>
```

Comment: Maybe, you just solve my other issue. (save the solution on the database or file?). I think save it to a file is a much smarter way, then save the solution to the database (I have +- 3000 students and +- 1000 internships). Could I get problems with memory usage with php. I do this in drupal (I already created a drupal module (the interface)). Thanks for your reply anyway, you do not respond, because this question, I might say here later (first i must program the fitness function).

Comment: If you have only raw data without relationships, the file storange solution may be useful. Else, The database is the best choose. However, for speed requirements I suggest you to think about embedded databases su as Berkley DB and SQLite3 wich can be used from php, java and C, C#. Remember, for big data computation, php is not a good solution. Expecially for huge amount of data elaboration (data mining, algorithms, and so on).

Comment: This can still be difficult to do everything to save in database or file with PHP (I hope PHP is strong enough) as you say is true! PHP is not really ideal to be programmed algorithms, the choice is because we use Drupal. (but, to ensure later :) ). Thanks for your contribution. I will soon be able to use this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The fitness function is completely dependent on your application.  It could be anything from how far a creature travels, to how many units you can build in Starcraft 2 at a certain time in the game, to measuring how closely an image resembles another.

Make sure it has enough granularity between good and bad though.